# PL/Python in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, plpython

I was writing a PL/Python function for PostgreSQl, with Python 2.7 and Python 3.5 already installed on Linux.
When I was trying to create extension plpythonu, I got an error, then I fixed executing in terminal the command `$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.3 postgresql-plpython-9.3`. I understand that this is some other package.

If I will not have Python 2.7/3.5 installed, and I will install the plpython package, will the user defined function still work? Is some how the PL/Python depending on Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will, the package is independent from standard python installation.